# Rails 4 way code to display iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe, ruby-on-rails-4

What is a proper way in rails 4 to display an iframe?

Until upgrade from rails 3.x to rails 4 the following code worked normally and displayed a page inside another as it should.

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" style="width:1050px;height:1230px;margin:0 auto;"></iframe>
```

Were there any updates in rails 4 made as to how an iframe should be rendered? I googled for some hours now without success and would greatly appreciate any answers or suggestions you might have!

Comment: Found that it's got sth to do with X-Frame-Options probably?

Comment: Probably here lies an answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options. Since I do not push stuff on our server I'll wait for partner to "wake-up" and will let you know if it works

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there should be any difference between Rails 3 and Rails 4 for this.  You're not really using any Rails features here.  You're just including standard html in a template.

Comment: We set x-frame-option to "GOFORIT", and now it displays properly.